# Is it possible to add 3D-touch without peek?

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

I have a collection of views (buttons) that can be toggled. They work as filters. Let's say it's a public transportation app, and you are presented with the question "What transportation type would you like to travel with?", and you get three options: "Bus", "Ferry" and "Train". You may click each of them to disable or enable them.

I would like to implement the ability to 3D-touch one of them, which will toggle that particular button to `on`, and all the other buttons to `off`.

I have used 3D-touch a few places in the app, but always with peek/pop. I'm struggling with adding 3D-touch without needing to return a `UIViewController` in the `previewingContext`-function. Is it possible to simply perform an action when 3D-touching?

I *could* perform my action in `previewingContext(::) -> UIViewController?`, but I don't want to return a UIViewController to be peeked. If I return `nil`, then I don't get the taptic(?) feedback.. And this function is called as soon as the user "might" force-touch, a bit before actually pressing.

Answer (score 3):

So it turns out that 3D-touch (or force-touch or whatever it's called) isn't *only* available through the implementation of `UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate`. This delegate's job is to decide what to present with peek/pop, while the core function of peek and pop can be accessed through a normal `UIGestureRecognizer`. I followed [this](https://medium.com/produkt-blog/3d-force-touch-beyond-peek-pop-c448edc2b1f5) guide to create my own ForceGestureRecognizer, but decided to subclass `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` instead of `UIGestureRecognizer` (to combine it with existing functions).
That guide, along with [this](https://medium.com/@sdrzn/make-your-ios-app-feel-better-a-comprehensive-guide-over-taptic-engine-and-haptic-feedback-724dec425f10) (to create the little shake feedback using `UINotificationFeedbackGenerator`), and together with some `CGAffineTransform`-changes based on the force of the touch really made it perfect.